# Как определить есть ли скролл-бар у блока или нет?

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Привет. Есть блок известной длинны и высоты, со свойством overflow-y: auto; в нем динамический контент, как узнать "влезает" ли весь контент в блок или нет? (есть ли у блока скролл-бар или нет)

Answer (score 2):

Пример [смотрим тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/2UbBK/1/). Подсветку сделал только для визуализации.

```
$('.box').wrapInner('<div class="fake"/>')
    .each(function(i,el){
    if($('.fake',el).height() > $(el).height()){
        $(el).after('Есть скроллбар');
    } else {
        $(el).after('Контент нормально помещается в блоке');
    }
});
```

Comment: Отличный пример, но реализация не совсем мне подходит, как вы думаете есть ли варианты без оборачивания контента в блок?

Comment: @Олег Б, вас смущает появление лишнего элемента? Так [его можно удалить][1] после выполнения операции. unwrap() тут может и не помочь, ну а просто замена - вполне.

   [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/2UbBK/2/

Comment: Я наверно не понимаю задачу, но почему не так?
http://jsfiddle.net/sr25a/2/

Comment: @moron только slice а не splice :)

Comment: @eicto да без разницы же, как привести к аутентичному js-массиву. Или нет?

Comment: @moron в ff не сработало.

> TypeError: property [].splice.call(...) is non-configurable and can't be deleted

Answer (score 2):

как вариант проверять изминение ширины контента внутри:

```
$('.box').each(function (i, e) {
    var $e = $(e);
    checker = $('<div>');
    $e.append(checker);
    var w = checker.innerWidth();
    $e.removeClass('hasScroll');
    $e.addClass('checkScroll');

    if (w < checker.innerWidth()) {
        $e.addClass('hasScroll');
        $e.after($('<div>').text('Есть скролл шириной ' + (checker.innerWidth() - w) + 'px').addClass('info'));
    }
    checker.remove();
    $e.removeClass('checkScroll');
});
```

CSS:

```
.checkScroll {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.hasScroll {
    background: #ff0;
}
.box {
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.info {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/2UbBK/4/